# Unstacking a data frame

Tags: r, stack, reshape2, melt

I have a data frame which looks like this:

```
d <- c("a", "b", "c", "a", "b", "c", "a", "b", "c")
par <- c("a1", "a2", "a3", "a4", "a5", "a6", "a7", "a8", "a9")
df1 <- as.data.frame(cbind(id, par))
```

I would like it to look like this:

```
a <- c("a1", "a4", "a7")
b <- c("a2", "a5", "a8")
c <- c("a3", "a6", "a7")
df2 <- data.frame(rbind(a, b, c))
```

Comment: What have you attempted?

Comment: I have limited experience / understanding of re-arranging data frames, so far I have tried using the functions unstack, dcast and melt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this with `unstack`

```
as.data.frame(t(unstack(df1,par~id)))
#  V1 V2 V3
#a a1 a4 a7
#b a2 a5 a8
#c a3 a6 a9
```

Or using `dcast` after creating a sequence column for the 'id' group.

```
library(data.table)#v1.9.5
dcast(setDT(df1)[, ind:= 1:.N, id], id~ind, value.var='par')
```

Comment: Thanks, I was trying to do this but not having much luck

Comment: @user4846627  Did this help or not?   Sorry, I didn't understand what you really meant.  Based on the example you provided, I am getting the expected result

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this as below, seems too messy though

```
id <- c("a", "b", "c", "a", "b", "c", "a", "b", "c")
par <- c("a1", "a2", "a3", "a4", "a5", "a6", "a7", "a8", "a9")
df1 <- as.data.frame(cbind(id, par))


ids <- levels(df1$id)

newdf <- list()

for ( i in 1:length(ids)){
tempdf <- df1[df1$id == ids[i],]
id <- tempdf[1,1]
parcels <- tempdf[,2]
row <- cbind(as.character(id), t(as.character(parcels)))
tempdf <- as.data.frame(row)
newdf[[i]] <- tempdf
}

df3 <- do.call(rbind.fill, newdf)
```

Comment: I was using a much larger data frame which resulted in a varying number of columns, hence rbind.fill